# dotnet cmdlet broken and continually tries to install .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, powershell, command-line

I am trying to get my `dotnet` CLI working. Everytime I invoke it, no matter the command it attempts to install .NET Framework 3.5, fails, and quits. Example:

```
PS C:\> dotnet --version
Installing .NET Framework 3.5...

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version 10.0.19041.844

Image Version: 10.0.19044.1348

Enabling feature(s)
[===================100.0%====================]
The operation completed successfully.

.NET Framework 3.5 should be installed

No installation media found!
Insert DVD or USB flash drive and run this file once again.

Press any key to continue . . .
```

I have used the `dotnet-core-uninstall` tool to remove everything that it can. I have uninstalled Visual Studio 2019 and 2017 and deleted the `/.dotnet` folder. The `dotnet` command issue persists with the same exact output, I don't even want 3.5 because that's not what my projects use (is that what the CLI runs on???). I don't know where it is pointing to or how to check and my google-fu powers have been exhausted.

*I also do not have access to edit the system environment variables directly and have to use powershell to do so*

**FIXED**
Turns out there was a `C:\windows\dotnet.bat` file that was taking precedence over the executables that get installed with any sdk. Deleting it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a stray `dotnet.bat` file situated in a directory that preceded that of the desired `dotnet.exe` CLI in your `$env:PATH` variable, `C:\windows\dotnet.bat`

Removing the batch file fixed the problem (calling `dotnet.exe` - i.e. *with the filename extension* - would have *bypassed* the problem).

The problem was discovered via the following [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) call, which lists all command forms / executable paths for the name `dotnet`, with the *effective* one listed first:

```
Get-Command dotnet -All
```